# AS3 (AIR) Mobile App: Send user back to open browser tab

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, android-intent, air

**Scenario:** An Android user clicks a link on browser page that emits an `intent` url that starts my app.

**Question:** Is there a way to direct the user back to that same open browser tab, without closing the app? 
If I use the AS3 function `navigateToURL` there is always a new tab regardless of what the target is set to, because the flash app is not contained in a web page. Also, I'm trying to avoid using the `StageWebView` because when the user is authenticated from outside the app, there is an issue with cookie-management. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open browser app with intent/parameters ([Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814896/launching-an-android-app-via-adobe-air-application), [iOS](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/933978)), but for that you need to be sure browser app supports intent tabId (index or name) and pass and remember tabId via initial intent from `Invoke` event. Also user can close the tab meanwhile, so you will have lots of edge cases to handle.

Comment: let's say the expected browser is Chrome, how would I send the intent including the tabId from actionscript?